# Prevent hiding parent modal form if a child MessageBox has shown

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have parent form, which I show using:

```
editForm.caption := editFormAddActionCaption;
editForm.prepareAndShow(processor);
```

Next, in some cases, pressing button `Ok` onto this modal parent
can causes appearing MessageBox, it is opening in such manear:

```
if (isRussian) then
  messageBoxResult := MessageBoxEx(windowHandle, PChar(bodyText), PChar(captionText), messageBoxConfID,
      makeLangId(LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT))
else
  messageBoxResult := MessageBox(windowHandle, PChar(bodyText), PChar(captionText), messageBoxConfID);
```

This lead to hiding parent modal form and after closing messageBox, parent modal form isn't return back.

Is there some ways to moderate appearing/disappearing parent modal form and child messagebox so after closing messagebox, parent form сould appear again?

Comment: Which window is `windowHandle`? Is it `editForm`'s handle?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `Application.MessageBox()` instead of `Windows.MessageBox()`?